# How can I get the last line position of PDF file using Python?

Tags: python, pdf

I am new in Python and creating PDF file using Python, ReportLab and PyPDF2 module. Please help me to find out the last line position of PDF file. Below is the explanation of my question.

For example,

I have one PDF file in which 10 lines are written. Now I wants to add another text into same PDF file. For this I wants to know position of the last line, So I can start another text from below of that line.

Below is sample of code using which i have extracted data from PDF file.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader


root= Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")        

def line_position():
    opn_pdf1= open("test_pdf.pdf","rb")
    read_pdf= PdfFileReader(opn_pdf1)
    print(read_pdf)
    num_page= read_pdf.getNumPages()
    print(num_page)
    page= read_pdf.getPage(num_page-1)
    data= page.extractText().splitlines()
    print (data)
    print(len(data))

Button(root,text= "PDF Last Line",command= line_position).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Also, let me know is there any way to read and extract data using reportlab instead of PyPDF2.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps a bit more...

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader


root= Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")        

def line_position():
    opn_pdf1= open("test.pdf","rb")
    read_pdf= PdfFileReader(opn_pdf1)
    print(read_pdf)
    num_page= read_pdf.getNumPages()
    print(num_page)
    page= read_pdf.getPage(num_page-1)
    data= page.extractText().splitlines()
    for i in reversed(range(0, len(data))):
        if data[i] != " ":
            print(data[i])
            break
        i -= 1
    print(len(data))

Button(root,text= "PDF Last Line",command= line_position).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, kavko for your reply. But I need the position of last line in PDF. This code gives me the text written in last line. 
As you know while you create PDF file using ReportLab you have to give the starting position to write content. I am finding about that position value.
Thanks again for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the y-coordinate on the PDF where the last line occurs. I don't believe PyPDF2 can do that. If you need x/y-coordinates you could use PyMuPDF. The following code uses PyMuPDF to print the y-coordinate of the last line.

```
import json
from tkinter import *

import fitz  # http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas


root= Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")


def line_position():
    read_pdf = fitz.open("test.pdf")
    num_page = read_pdf.pageCount
    print(num_page)
    page = read_pdf[num_page - 1]
    # http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/app2/#json
    data = json.loads(page.getText(output='json'))
    print(data)
    highest_y = -1
    for block in data['blocks']:
        if 'lines' in block:
            for line in block['lines']:
                for span in line['spans']:
                    if span['text'].strip():
                        print(span)
                        highest_y = max((highest_y, span['bbox'][3]))
    print(highest_y)
    read_pdf.close()


Button(root, text="PDF Last Line", command=line_position).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried to install fitz but getting "Fatal Error: fitz.h: No such file or directory" error.


Can you please tell me that "PyMuPDF" work only for Windows? I am using Raspberry Pi. May due to this it will not install.

Also, tell me how to install this.

Comment: It says it works for Windows, Mac, and Linux. Installation instructions are here: http://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/. I prefer installing with pip: `pip install [--upgrade] PyMuPDF`.